# A regularity result in Bochner spaces, simmetry of second derivatives (time and space)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, regularity-theory-of-pdes, hyperbolic-equations, bochner-spaces

For a function $u:(0,T)\to L^2(\Omega)$, assume that we have shown that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\partial_i u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and also that $\partial_t u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. Can we deduce that $\partial_t(\partial_i u) \in L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ as well? In that case, do the partial derivatives commute, that is $\partial_t(\partial_i u)=\partial_i(\partial_t u)$ a.e. in $(0,T)\times\Omega$?

Comment: I think a relevant example is: $u = t-|x|$ for $|x|\le t$, and $u = 0$ otherwise,

Comment: Very useful example, indeed. Thank you.